# How to Remove Checked Table Row Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove table rows which it checkbox has been checked. Here is the code I can add rows to table but I do not know how to remove only checked one.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#add").on("click",function(){
  $('table').append('<tr> <td><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"></td><td>Color Option : <input type="color" name="favcolor"></td><td>Item ID: <input type="text" name="firstname"></td> </tr>');
});
});
```

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/yNLKE/1/) and let me know how to remove only checked row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an trailing space in the ID of remove button remove it

```
<button id="remove" type="button">Reomve Selected Color</button>
```

then add a click handler and use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has) to find rows with checked checkboxes

```
$("#remove").on("click", function () {
    $('table tr').has('input[name="vehicle"]:checked').remove()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mKAWt/)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
  $("#remove").on("click",function(){
     $('input:checked').each(function() {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
 });
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNLKE/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

you should remove all the input

```
$("tr input[type='chekbox']:cheked").remove()
```

Comment: That would leave the `tr` though, explicitly not what the OP wants; also both typos will stop the selector matching any elements.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Row

HTML for button (change 'myTable' for your actual table ID)

```
<input id="removeRowBtn" onclick="deleteRow('myTable')" value="Remove selected row" name="removeRowBtn" type="button">
```

Javascript (with an extra fadeOut effect)

```
var deleteRow = function(tableID) {
    var ID = "#" + tableID;
    var rowCount = jQuery(ID + " tbody tr").length;

    jQuery(ID + " input:checked").each(function() {

        if (rowCount > 1)
        {
            jQuery(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(function () { 
                jQuery(this).remove();
            });
            rowCount--;
        }
        else
            alert("Cannot remove all rows.");
    });

    return false;
}
```

### Add/duplicate Row (extra, not an answer)

HTML for button (change 'myTable' for your actual table ID)

```
<input id="addRowBtn" onclick="addRow('myTable')" value="Add row" name="addRowBtn" type="button">
```

Javascript (duplicates first row, with an fadeIn effect)

```
var addRow = function(tableID) {
    var ID = "#" + tableID;
    var rowCount = jQuery(ID + " tbody tr").length;
    if (rowCount < 5) { // limit the user from creating more rows
        jQuery(ID + " tbody tr:first").clone().appendTo(ID).hide().fadeIn();
    } else {
        alert("Cannot add more than 5 rows.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: I use jQuery instead of $ because of possible conflicts. The code assumes your rows are within a tbody as well, to follow HTML5 standards and to avoid possible conflicts with a thead or tfoot. I also know it might be cleaner to use click event instead of html attribute onclick, but this has it's pros as well. Might help someone at least.